# Focus without scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I put the focus on a textarea by focus function, I have a window scrolling but i don't want it.

I've not already focus because i stay on another textarea, I capture on blur event to save content of the textarea before to go to the new textarea clicked. But the cursor don't go in the new textarea but stay in the old textarea. I can use JQuery too.

I'm using this code:

```
ed.on('click', function(o) {    
    o.preventScroll = true;
    o.preventDefault();
    o.stopPropagation();
    $(this).focus();
    cont = 0;
});
```

I don't want the window scrolling.

Comment: Please provide enough HTML as well to create a [mre]

Comment: What's your goal with that? How does a clicked element not _already_ have focus? Maybe if you explain your reasoning we can offer other solutions. Also, this appears to be jQuery. Please tag accordingly,

Comment: @isherwood  I've not already focus because i stay on another textarea, I capture on blur event to save content of the texarea before to go to the new textarea cliccked. But the cursor don't go in the new textarea but stai in the old textarea. I can use JQuery too. Thank's.

Comment: Don't tell me down here. Revise your question. :) Take the [tour] so you know how this site works. I also asked you to tag jQuery.